# Making versions in git

Tags: git, version-control, github

I am trying to understand how version control works in git/github. I can clone, pull, merge or add and remove remotes. What I don't understand is how to separate versions.

Here is an example. Suppose I have a entire site stored in `github.com/user/foobar_site` Now, assume I have completely remade my local copy of `foobar_site`, but I don't want to push this and have it get mixed with my remote copy. So, what I would like is to keep my remote intact and push my local to it without mixing the two. The end result would be, I will be able to `git clone` the first version of `foobar_site` and the second version at any time.

Is such thing possible? if so, then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git push` doesn't mix (*merge* in git-speak) anything. It takes your local copy, and tells the remote side that this is now the current version. The old version will still be available using its commit ID, or you can create a tag or branch to refer to it.

`git log` will show you all previous versions of your repo.

```
git commit -m "Old stuff"

(change loads of files)

git commit -m "New changes"

git log --oneline

10a3fe2 New changes
7f0ceaa Old stuff
```

You can get back to *any* old committed version of your code with `git checkout`:

```
git checkout 7f0ceaa
```

And back to the current version with

```
git checkout master
```

Comment: Thanks. So, if I wanted to download the old stuff, I would be enough to do, `git checkout 7f0ceaa` and then `git clone https://github.com/user/foobar_site.git`? is that it?

Comment: @iOi, you may also want to [read up on tags](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging), which will let you give commits meaningful names like `v1.0` or `release-12`.

Comment: @iOi Clone first, then checkout.